# Linked list cstring insertion sort

Tags: c++

This is my code for an insertion-sort, sorting via the cstring member of the node. The current code only inserts before the head. The code encapsulated in comments is the sorted insertion I am trying to make work. I'm thinking I have to use a predecessor and successor pointer, but maybe it's the comparison that is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "groclist.h"

void insert_item(Grocery_Item_Ptr &head, int quantity, const char name[])
{
bool exists = false;
bool done = false;
Grocery_Item_Ptr temp = NULL;
Grocery_Item_Ptr current = NULL;
Grocery_Item_Ptr pred = NULL;
Grocery_Item_Ptr succ = NULL;

if (head == NULL) {
    head = new Grocery_Item;
    head->quantity = quantity;
    strncpy(head->name, name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN);
    head->next = NULL;
    return;
}
else {
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strncmp(current->name, name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN) == 0) {
            current->quantity += quantity;
            exists = true;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (exists) {
        current = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else {
        current = head;
    }

    if (!exists) {
        temp = new Grocery_Item;
        temp->quantity = quantity;
        strncpy(temp->name, name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN);
/*                                                                                                                                 
        while (!done || current != NULL) {                                                                                     
            if (strncmp(current->name, name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN) < 0) {                                                                                                              
                pred = current;
                succ = current->next;
                current->next = temp;
                temp->next = succ;

                done = true;                                                                                                   
            }                                                                                                                  
            if (!done) {                                                                                                       
                current = current->next;                                                                                       
            }                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                      
*/

        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
}

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your input guys, if only for having me think about it in different ways. However my result is quite different, and I must truly thank my whiteboard.

```
if (strncmp(name, head->name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN) < 0) {
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    temp = NULL;
}
else {
    pred = head;
    current = head->next;    
    do {
        if (strncmp(name, current->name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN) < 0) {
            pred->next = temp;
            temp->next = current;
            done = true;
        }
        else if (current->next == NULL) {
            current->next = temp;
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            pred = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (done) {
            pred = NULL;
            current = NULL;
        }
    } while (!done && current != NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are missing is keeping a reference to the predecessor while searching. This is necessary in order to keep the chain intact.

Here is a draft that should work (currently untested!):

```
while (!done || current != NULL)
{ 
    //If we found the place to insert
    if (strncmp(current->name, name, MAX_ITEM_NAME_LEN) < 0)
    {
        //If the place to insert was at head
        if(pred == NULL)
        {
            //The new node becomes the head
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            //Set the previous nodes next to point at this node.
            pred->next = temp;
        }

        //Always set the node to be inserted's next
        //pointing to the node we should be inserted before
        temp->next = current;
    done = true;        
  }                     
    if (!done)
    {
        //No match, keep looking but keep an updated pred pointer
        pred = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It's just pseudocode, but maybe it helps:

if(head == NULl)
    {
          //make newnode as head
}

if(head.name == new name)
    {
    //update quantity
    }

if(head.name <new name)
    {
    //insert newnode before head
    //make newnode as head
    }

if (new name > head.name)

{
    current = head;
    succ = current.next;

    while (succ && new name <succ.name)
        {
                 curent = succ;
         succ = succ.next
        }


    if(succ = NULL)
        current->next = newnode
    else
        if new name = succ->name
            update quantity
        else
            curent->next = newnode
            newnode->next = succ;
}
```